# How to make client-side particles visible to other players? (Server-side)

Tags: lua, roblox

Basically, I have a LocalScript in StarterCharacterScripts. This LocalScript, named "Fireball", handles the casting of fireballs and other abilities. These abilities uses parts with a particles. When testing in Roblox Studio, everything works just fine.

The problem is when I tested it with another player, the fireballs and other abilities are only visible to the player who casted the ability or other words, it's only in the client.

I can use some help on how to solve this problem, I've seen people talking about RemoteEvents and/or RemoteFunctions but there's not much examples on how to use it.

I've tried looking for examples everywhere on how to allow client-side particles to appear in other players' screens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you should never create Instances client-sided (except for UI etc. that is actually client-sided). You should actually use a **Remote Event**. If you don't know, it is just a signal from the client to the server that something should happen right now (or vice versa).

Since you have not give us any code, I can't edit your code but you should then add the **Remote Event**, let's say you call it '*CreateFireball*'. In your local script you then reference this RemoteEvent with this code:

```
local RepStorage = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage')
local CreateFireball = RepStorage:WaitForChild('CreateFireball')
```

Then at the part in your local script where you actually **create** the fireball you cut the code (Ctrl+X) and write:

```
CreateFireball:FireServer()
```

Then in a **server script** you write

```
local RepStorage = game:GetService('ReplicatedStorage')
local CreateFireball = RepStorage:WaitForChild('CreateFireball')

CreateFireball.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
   --and then you paste (Ctrl+V) the code you just cut
end)
```

I hope that helped!

Comment: hello, sorry for not providing the script (it's messy).

what I have here is a snippet of the fireball mechanic. This snippet handles the creation of fireballs via cloning to the workspace from replicated storage, and the changing of its position to simulate movement. It also handles collision events with parts of the world and humanoids.

[link]https://pastebin.com/xez597fh